# How do I shrink the height of a div to accommodate more content?

Tags: css

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
.-------------------.u
|#content           |u
'-------------------'u
.-------------------.u
|#menu              |u
'-------------------'u
.-------------------.u
|#morecontent       vu
|                   vu
|                   vu
'-------------------'u
```

`u`'s represent the body scrollbar and `v`'s the one created from `#morecontent`'s `overflow: auto` property. I have `#menu` contain dynamic data so sometimes it takes more than one line but right now `#morecontent` is sized to fit only one. How can I make the height of `#morecontent` adjust itself so it doesn't cause the `u` scrollbar to be scrollable or "enabled". I guess when I have more than one line? I know I should be using `%`'s and I tried using `max-height` but it didn't really work the way I wanted...

Comment: If you don't set the height for `#morecontent` then it will be as high as its contents. Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: @zvonimir the stuff inside `#morecontent` is usually taller than the actual div so the `v` scrollbar is almost always scrollable.

Comment: But what defines div's height? Did you set `#morecontent {height: something}`? If you just remove it, the div should be as high as needed... Why don't you show the HTML and CSS involved? That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your div uses only max-height and min-height. Do not use height.
If you want its height to go forever, don't set anything.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/9QNUG/

note: you did not say if the content above was dynamic, but i am assuming not from your description, you will need to play with the heights in the example to get them to match yours.

Answer (score -1):

Use `position: fixed` to make the layout more concrete and Javascript to resize the #morecontent div. There is no way to make it resize when the other div does with XHTML/CSS.